# How do you guarantee safety when validating Keycloak (OIDC) tokens without making requests to the Keycloak API?

Tags: oauth, jwt, keycloak, openid-connect

There is a lot of information on OAuth, OIDC and Keycloak, but the main thing every tutorial seems to gloss over is offline validation. The only information I found is in the Keycloak docs on RPT introspection:

> No. Just like a regular access token issued by a Keycloak server, RPTs also use the JSON web token (JWT) specification as the default format. If you want to validate these tokens without a call to the remote introspection endpoint, you can decode the RPT and query for its validity locally. Once you decode the token, you can also use the permissions within the token to enforce authorization decisions.

If I wanted to verify a user's request with an authorization token, I would make a request to the Keycloak introspection (or userinfo?) API. I'm not completely sure, but I would guess that Keycloak then verifies the info encoded in the JWT with the Keycloak user database.

However, what if I don't want to make a Keycloak request on every API request? This could improve system performance by limiting the amount of HTTP requests. There are mentions of JWT signature validations and reading the scope and user information encoded in the JWT, but I don't see how this guarantees safety. Isn't it possible to just generate any old JWT, encode any information you want and basically spoof an authorization token? How would I check if the user mentioned in the JWT really exists in the Keycloak database?

I think I am missing some crucial part of this technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, in ASP.NET Core, an API that receives a JWT token will, at startup, download the public signing keys from the token provider, and by default, it will refresh the keys every 24 hours.

So, when the API receives a JWT token, it will do various checks to validate the token, including:

- Validating the signature using the provider public signing key
- Validate the audience claim (is the token intended for me?)
- Validate the expiry date

The API should not need to query anything against the token provider (keycloak) to let the user in.

However, then we have authorization (What the user is allowed to do), which is a different thing, and that all depends on your requirements.

JWT is all about who the user is; if the token is valid, you can trust that information.

With JWT-tokens, your API can work almost offline from the token provider. It can even be 100% disconnected if you copy the public signing key manually into the API.